# Calling a REST API using Azure function App and store data in Azure container

Tags: python-requests, azure-functions

I have a requirement to call a rest api and store the resulting json in azure storage container. I have tried standalone python coding to extract the data from rest api and able to successfully receive the data from api that has pagination. Now I need to integrate/modify this python coding inside Azure Function and will ultimately store the resulting json data in a azure storage container. I am fairly new to Azure and hence need your guidance on how to tweak this code to suit in Azure function that will in turn push the json to azure container finally.

```
response = requests.post(base_url,
                        auth=(client_id, client_secret),                         data={'grant_type':grant_type,'client_id':client_id,'client_secret':client_secret,'resource':resource})
acc_token_json = response.json()
access_token = json.loads(response.text)
token = access_token['access_token']
#call API to know total pages
API_Key = 'xxxxx'

api_url='https://api.example.com?pageSize=10&page=1&sortBy=orderid&sortDirection=asc'
headers = {
        'Authorization': token,
        'API-Key': API_Key,
    }
r = requests.get(url=api_url, headers=headers).json()
total_record=int(r['pagination']['total'])
total_page=round(total_record/500)+1
#loop through all pages
all_items = []
for page in range(0, total_page):
        url = "https://api.example.com?pageSize=500&sortBy=orderid&sortDirection=asc&page="+str(page)             
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()  
        response_data=response['data']
        all_items.append(response_data)
```

Your inputs/guidances are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the logic in the body of the function.(Function is just set the condition of trigger.)

For example, if you are based on HttpTrigger:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    '''
    #Put the your logic code here.
    '''
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This is a test.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

And you can also use blob output to achieve your requirement, it is easier, have a look of this offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python#example

Let me know if have any problem.

Comment: Hi Bowman, 
Thanks a lot for your response. I will give it a try and get back if I am stuck at some step.Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Yes I am getting below error while running azure functions in portal.

Comment: Yes I am getting below error while running azure functions in portal. 
"Result: Failure Exception: TypeError: unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported type "<class zure_functions_worker.bindings.generic.GenericBinding'>" for Python type "list".

It seems because I am looping through multiple pages and trying to append the results to an array all_items[] as mentioned in above post but func def is func.Out[str]

Can you let me know if this is right way of assigning to bloboutput - outputBlob.set(all_items)

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, outputBlob: func.Out[str]) -> None:

Comment: Hi again, in a nutshell pls let me know how should i pass the array output to blob and how should the function definition header look like in python code i.e. func.Out() thing..

Comment: Hi, I figured it out via another blog. I just had to str statement infront -  "outputBlob.set(str(all_items)). I have another question regarding the connection string that we mention in "localsettings.json". I have copy pasted the connection from the storage account under "AzureWebJobsStorage". Does it mean that we cannot deploy all the resources(resource group, storage account, functionapp, functions) in a single go when we develop because we don't know the connection string of the storage account until that resource is ready and deployed? Sorry if it's a stupid question, learning stuffs.

Comment: @Kesavan Yes, under normal circumstances, it is not possible to deploy all resources at once. (ResourceGroup, Storage Account, FunctionApp, function) You need to prepare others before deploy function. But if you use integrated development tools, such as Visual Studio, then you can easily deploy all resources. (It just takes a long time.)

Comment: @Kesavan Do you have any more adoubts?

Comment: yes one more question. My azure functions makes call to a rest api and stores data(json file) in my storage container in the folder format like this --> year=2020/month=12/day=1/xxxxx.json. It is a timer trigger function that runs 5times in a day. How do I extract/fetch the timestamp at which the last extraction happened in python coding? Bcos I need to know when was the last extraction from api in order to use that information in the api call by passing time range parameter as part of the api query parameter like --> timestamp >=(GE) last extraction timestamp)